# is it possible to mark /assign default workspace /my workspace as Premium per user in power bi service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I recently too premium per user license in power BI to explore its features and capabilities as part of my learning efforts;

By default, there is a workspace existed which is My Workspace; however, I created an additional workspace in the service. As I attempted to nominate /mark "My Workspace -- under premium per user, the relevant options were disabled; and when I attempted the same process with manually created (non-default) workspace, there were options enabled.

Does it indicate that default-workspace (i.e. My Workspace) cannot be marked for permium per user (usage)? Would anyone please help me understand the scenario.

Thank you for giving your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't flag your 'My Workspace' as a Premium Per User (PPU), or if you have it a  PBI Premium Capacity (PPC).

My Workspace is your sandbox to host your reports, and is not suited to sharing reports/dashboards/dataset/dataflows from.

The normal workspaces will have features above your 'My Workspace' capabilities, for example Workspace Apps, Deployment Pipelines and security/user controls.

PPU & PPC are designed for sharing items across users/workspaces/features so it will work with those enhanced features not available in My Workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, John

Comment: No problem, if you think the answer helps please click accept